# Link dynamic and manual data i Google sheets using QUERY

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

1. 

I have a Google spreadsheet named "Words" with a number of words which are divided into categories.

2)
In Google spreadsheet named "UNIQUE + MANUALLY" I make a unique list in (UNIQUE category) from category in "Words".
To the unique list I would like to have attached a manual word.

How do I get column (MANUALLY Category groups) to follow (UNIQUE category) so the list does not change when new words and categories are added?

Comment: Formulae will always automatically update whenever they can, so the cells will need to bo populated with static text rather than imported from another range with a formula. You'd need to use Apps Script for this, would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Anything that can solve the problem will be a solution. :-)
Do you have a solution with scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use a script on button click to run the query and statically add the text into the desired cells.*

#### The Idea:

The idea is very similar to how the formula currently works:

- Get a list of all words
- Remove duplicates and blank cells
- Alphabetise them
- Insert them into the correct column

#### Code Example:

Assuming that your column is `'UNIQUE + MANUALLY'!B2:B` and the words are all in `'words'!A2:A`:

```js
function getUniqueWords() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const wordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("words")
  const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("UNIQUE + MANUALLY")

  const wordsToSort = wordsSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues()
    .flat().filter(function (el) {
      return el != ""
    }).filter(function (v, i, s) {
      return s.indexOf(v) === i
    }).sort().map(x => [x])

  destSheet.getRange("A2:A").clear()
  destSheet.getRange(2, 1, wordsToSort.length, 1).setValues(wordsToSort)
}
```

You can add this script to your Sheet by following the `Tools > Script editor` menu item, pasting this function into the editor, and saving the script. Make sure to press `Run` at least once to authorise the script so that it can run on your behalf.

If you want to add this to a button click in the Sheet itself, you can create a Drawing or add an image into a Sheet from the `Insert` menu item, and then with the image loaded into the sheet, you can click it, select the vertical ellipsis menu (`⋮`) which appears in the top-right of the image, select `Assign script` and in the dialog box enter the function name (in this case, `getUniqueWords`, without the succeeding `()`).

Comment: Hi Rafa

Thank you so much for sharing. 

The script works perfectly, so that part I will continue to work on.

However, I still need to solve the problem of matching the 2 word types, but I think I will succeed now that I can decide when to retrieved the data, with the script.

This was very helpful thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to sort values from "words B2: B" in "UNIQUE + MANUALLY A2: A" such that new added words in "words B2: B" which do not also have a value in "words C2: C",
is printed at the bottom of the list, without changing the order of the existing words in "UNIQUE + MANUALLY A2: A" ??

It will be a great help

Comment: @Smedegaard it is - but it’s a bit more involved so might be better to ask a new question to get dedicated answers :)

Comment: consider it done :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68317179/link-dynamic-and-manual-data-i-google-sheets-using-apps-scrip