# Link dynamic and manual data in Google sheets using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dynamic form in Google sheets that needs to be paired with some manual words. I use this script in Google sheets to retrieve the unique glossary when I click a button.

The script does the following:

- Get a list of all words
- Remove duplicates and blank cells
- Alphabetise them
- Insert them into the correct column

The script looks like this:

```
function getUniqueCategory() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const wordsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("words")
  const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test")

  const wordsToSort = wordsSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues()
    .flat().filter(function (el) {
      return el != ""
    }).filter(function (v, i, s) {
      return s.indexOf(v) === i
    }).sort().map(x => [x])

  destSheet.getRange("J2:J").clear()
  destSheet.getRange(2, 10, wordsToSort.length, 1).setValues(wordsToSort)
}
```

What I need is to remember which words are new and which are old.
Could the solution be to make an extra `const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName` which looks at what words already exist?

Demo sheets:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f3glctP5pwcdznVr5Wl03ZutoKUA_BGAf_Q1KCMmcxs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what you mean by `which words are new and which are old.`? Where and how are new words added, and what do you want to happen exactly?

Comment: Yes, of course.
1) A new word is written in the "words" column A2: A
2) In "Test column A2: A the unique words are retrieved from "words"
3) In column B it is possible to assign "category groups from Manual subcategory groups
4) I would like words from UNIQUE category that have NOT been assigned to a category groups to be written in UNIQUE category (new) and all others to be in UNIQUE category (Last retrieved)

Comment: Is it possible?